# Balance updation problem of ethereum process due to block number updation took more time

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

We are integrated the ethereum on new server, then we send the balance to my ethereum wallet address. The balance is updated on the ethereum.io site with current ethereum block number but in our server the balance is not updated because of the block number started from 1 so it took more time to reach the current ethereum block number. we are waiting upto 20 days but till now the block not reached to the block number shown in ethereum.io(upto the 2000000 block number it updated within one day but after that it took this much of time). Is there any solution for this problem recommend to us. if we do wrong anything please correct us. Thanks in advance

Comment: what client are you using? how are you syncing your blockchain?

Comment: we are using go-ethereum, and use the following way to start the ethereum geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" and we can see the block number increasing but it too slow